# Apache 2.4 crashes when audio file is played

Tags: php, apache, moodle

I maintain Moodle 3.10 and with Ubuntu 18.04 (php/7.2/fpm fast cgi), 32 GBRAM and works well with 70 concurrent users to take quiz through intra network. They are all able to take quiz and submit without any issue. Today for an English exam, I placed an mp3 file (<6mb) in autoplay mode this caused server crash. when using button to play audio this did not happen but during autoplay it crashed.

The apache error log during one such event that caused crash:

```
[Wed Jan 27 08:39:16.932221 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6615:tid 140649221256960] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.7.80:59165] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://examle.com/mod/quiz/view.php?id=4856
```

Any approach to play audio or video file in quizzes? like tweaking php or apache settings or setting media servers Kaltura will help?

TIA

Comment: You are probably using PHP-FPM for mp3 files. Only use PHP-FPM for .php files

Comment: Please show httpd.conf in your question.

Comment: Add the following to the configuration to understand more:LogLevel notice proxy_fcgi:trace8 core:trace8 http_module:trace8

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions of httpd and mod_proxy_fcgi you can simply add timeout= to the end of the ProxyPassMatch

For older versions it was a little more complicated, e.g.:

```
<Proxy fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000>
ProxySet timeout=1800
</Proxy>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.php.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/<docroot>/$1
```